# alt-b, alt-f does not work in xterm

Tags: cygwin, xterm, xming

I use xterm under cygwin/Xming.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (jump one word backwards) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> (one word forward) do not work, but instead display some diacritical characters or something.

I have created a file .Xresources and a file .Xdefaults in my home dir, each containing only this line:

```
xterm*eightBitInput: false
```

Yet the problem persists.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to do the same.

I had to add:

```
xterm*metaSendsEscape: true
```

in my .Xresources file and then restart my system. Wouldn't work without the restart.

Answer (score 1):

I think the relevant resource is metaSendsEscape, which you'll want to set to true.